# java GC when all objects die young

Tags: java, garbage-collection

What GC settings would you suggest for the case, when literaly all objects die very young?
I have 8 Gb heap, by default 1.495 Gb used for Eden and 191 Mb for each Survivor space.
I see, that Tenured never grows, it remains always like 0.01% occupied.
But each 2-3 minutes I have the Eden collection.
Abandance of unused space in Tenured makes no sense (or makes it?)?
What would be your suggestion?

Comment: Not clear why somebody downgraded the question.
In my case literally all work happens in Eden, never in Tenured Space, 
With that I afraid to maximize the Eden and reduce the Tenured, because I have no idea is it dangerous or not. Also I do not want increase minor collections time by increasing the eden. With all that I see like 6Gb Tenured space is always empty and everything works in 1.5Gb Eden.

Comment: "put on hold as opinion based".
I'm not getting that.
Why?
What could be wrong in opinions, specified by accepted answer?
If you put something on hold, you need specify why, not just excersize your points. Shame.
It is perfect answer on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not dangerous. As long as the heap comfortably fits into main memory you won't have a problem. I also suggest you use compressed oops where possible (by keeping the heap < 32 GB)
I often have an Eden of 24 GB so that if I produce 1 GB if garbage an hour I get one minor collection a day. (Actually I schedule a full collection at a known time every day)

One thing you should seriously consider is using Java 8 as the JVM has an effective escape analysis. This means that very short lived objects are placed on the stack and don't use the heap at all.

The thing to remember is that the cost of collecting the Eden is basically proportional to the number and size of objects retained. Having an Eden where you keep almost nothing, an 8 GB eden took about twice as long as an 8 MB eden to collect.
Increasing the Eden size can give you objects more time to die in the Eden space and avoid being copied to survivor.

Comment: 1)Do you think it is normal to set -XX:NewRatio=0.5, meaning  - I want young twice as big as tenured?
I hardly imagine, that it is possible to leave tiny Tenured and large young.. :).

2)It does not matter for Java 8, that the app compiled by Java 6 to make the trick with stack, that you mentioned?
Thanks.

Comment: @VladimirNabokov you can't set a new size which is not an integer AFAIK. But yes, I often set the Eden to be 10x that of tenured. Java optimises the code dynamically at runtime based on how you use it. How it was compiled shouldn't matter.

Comment: @VladimirNabokov Btw just because I set the Eden 10x the tenured doesn't mean it makes sense for 95% of use cases. Tuning for one gc a day is an extreme example. My point is; there is no problem doing this.

Comment: Peter,
How you set Eden larger than Tenured without NewRatio?
(I did it with  -XX:NewSize)
Thanks.

Comment: There is 500+ gc tuning parameters :P I use the -Xmn= to set the new size and the -XX:SurvivorRatio= to set the ratio of Eden to survivor. If all objects die in Eden I set the survivor ratio as high as 100 to maximise the Eden.